# How to find out if a file is in variable of type File?

Tags: java

How to find out if the file is in the variable, I have a variable of type File, 
how can I figure out if the uploaded file is in it. I used the following but ran into java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
import java.io.File;

public void checkFile(File file){
1>> if (file.isFile)
2>> if (file != null)
....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as below,

```
if (file != null && file.isFile()) {

}
```

Comment: Yeah noted that and changed